# 1px white vertical line on screen?

Tags: macos

On my iMac, I have a 1px white vertical line all the way on the right of my screen on my wallpaper. I can confirm this is not a hardware issue nor dead pixels, because when I change my wallpaper alignment to "fit to screen," the white line disappears. It only shows when I have wallpaper that extends to the edge of the screen. It also shows up in screenshots of my screen.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What size is your wallpaper file (in pixels, width x height), and what resolution is your iMac's screen?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: It sounds like your wallpaper isn't fitting your screens resolution